# Example of an infinite dimensional complex vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My notes say that the example of an infinite dimensional complex vector space is the space of complex polynomials 
$$\mathbb{V}=\left\{c_0+c_1z+....+c_kz^k|\forall k\in\mathbb{Z},\forall c_i\in\mathbb{C}\right\} $$
I know that the axioms for a vector space include addition axioms and the axioms of scalar multiplication, but provided a vector in the vector space is defined to me. What is actually the vector in this vector space on which addition/scalar multiplication is defined? The vector comprising the co-efficients of these polynomials?? or is it something else??

Comment: The vectors are the polynomials themselves. When talking about abstract vector spaces, you have to open your mind to think of a vector as "an object satisfying the vector space axioms" rather than "an ordered list of numbers"

Comment: @eepperly16 Ok, will need a time for that to sink in, but then how would you define the dot product in this vector space?

Comment: When we talk about vector spaces, we tend to say "inner product" rather then dot product. It turns out there are lots of inner products on any vector space. One nice one is $$ \langle p, q \rangle = \int_a^b p(x) \overline{q(x)} dx$$ for any real constants $a$ and $b$

Comment: A vector space is not *required* to have a dot product (or *inner product*). Your question asked about *scalar multiplication* which is simply multiplying each coefficient of the polynomial by the respective complex scalar.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. If I have further queationa, I'll ask :)